# Why "App is running" (On Going notification) not dismissing automatically in case of "no use" (Android 8.0+)?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have foreground Service for Android 8.0 and above. And it is working fine.

**But,**

Notification is not dismissing automatically even if App is removed from recent (see image). And in that case App will not have any stuff to do.

[image]

**Questions,**

- Why its not get dismissed when "no use"?
- Is there any way to dismiss notification when "no use"?

Comment: Foreground notifications can't get dismissed by design. It's used for services, so it'll stay there until the service, not the app, is terminated. "Force quit" should do it too. There's some workarounds to hide them, but they're heavily API dependent IIRC.

Comment: So may I know when services should gets terminate? Because I know that when app isn't running, there will no use of service. So I think it should get terminate. Is it?

Comment: Not unless you manually kill it. Aside that, services run in the background until the OS decides it's time for it to be killed, or until reboot. You probably want https://stackoverflow.com/a/31586477/6296561